# ACPI BIOS Error (bug) Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, bios, acpi

[image: the image is for people that are saying kali is a specialized tool and not to be run on hardware your wrong its a distribution and yes it can.]Hi all I am using Kali Linux. It is working okay but logs in `dmesg` show that I have this error. I have googled it but not having any luck and before you say anything look at the screenshot yes it can run on hardware Bare Metal that enables you to have access to GPU for hash cat. I have installed NVIDIA drivers from Kali walk through the OS is running fine and has been since I installed it but the error displays before I get login splash screen and its annoying but don't affect the running of Kali or that I can notice.

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200925/psargs-330)
[    2.114652] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP05.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200925/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Do you have a actual problem, or are you creating a problem in your head based on this log entry?

Comment: the error shows on boot its annoying and i am looking for a way of fixing the issue but OS works fine

Comment: Presumably Kali isn't your main OS (it is a specialized tool, not a normal OS) so there really is no reason to worry. If you _are_ using Kali as your main OS, then that is what you should change. See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360).

Comment: It being possible doesn't imply it is also sensible.

Comment: You don't... it's a bug in your bios and motherboard vendors can't be bothered to fix their buggy bios.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages seem to be about [ACPI extensions for display adapters](https://uefi.org/specs/ACPI/6.4/Apx_B_Video_Extensions/acpi-extensions-for-display-adapters-introduction.html).

In the ACPI specification (linked above) the `_BCL` method is described as "Query list of brightness control levels supported". Apparently your ACPI BIOS has declared that it supports this extension method, but when the Linux ACPI interpreter is parsing the ACPI tables provided by the BIOS, it cannot find this method.

In plain English: your system BIOS/UEFI firmware has told the Linux kernel that there is an ACPI-based method for controlling the brightness of the backlight of the laptop's display, but it turns out the actual code to implement it seems to be missing. This is usually not a problem, as the GPU drivers often have alternative methods for controlling the backlight brightness without involving ACPI.

The scary error messages are generated because the same code that checks the validity of ACPI methods is used with all ACPI methods: both the important and the less important methods are checked before use, and all ACPI implementation errors (firmware bugs) detected by the kernel will be reported in the same way. I think some very common nuisance errors have received special treatment, but the backlight-related messages might be important for someone troubleshooting why their laptop's backlight adjustment does not work.

Unfortunately, your choices for fixing these messages are limited to:

- installing a BIOS update and hoping it will fix the issue
- trying various display-related BIOS settings and hoping some combination of them will not have this issue (particularly if you have a dual-GPU laptop)
- setting the kernel console log level so high that the message won't be displayed (but this might cause you not see other important error messages, if your system e.g. develops a hardware fault)
- developing a kernel patch to selectively silence those particular messages in your specific hardware model (requires some programming skills, but might be easier than you think)

Answer (score 0):

Try rotating through the kernel options.

Worst case scenario run it with `acpi=off` or `noacpi` but if you're not experiencing issues I would just leave it as it it.

**acpi=off OR noacpi**
This parameter disables the whole ACPI system. This may prove very useful, for example, if your computer does not support ACPI or if you think the ACPI implementation might cause some problems (for instance random reboots or system lockups).

**acpi=force**
Activates the ACPI system even if your computer BIOS date is older than 2000. This parameter overrides acpi=off and can also be used with current hardware if the ACPI support is not activated despite apm=off.

**pci=noacpi OR acpi=noirq**
These parameters disable the PCI IRQ routing

**pci=acpi**
This parameter activates the PCI IRQ routing

**acpi_irq_balance**
ACPI is allowed to use PIC interrupts to minimize the common use of IRQs.

**acpi_irq_nobalance**
ACPI is not allowed to use PIC interrupts.

**acpi=oldboot**
Deactivates the ACPI system almost completely; only the components required for the boot process will be used.

**acpi=ht**
Deactivates the ACPI system almost completely; only the components required for hyper threading will be used.

**noapic**
Disable the "Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller (APIC)".

**nolapic**
Disable the "local APIC".

**apm=off OR noapm**
Disable the Advanced Power Management.

**irqpoll**
Changes the way the kernel handles interrupt calls (set it to polling). Can be useful in case of hardware interrupt issues.

**acpi.power_nocheck=1 OR acpi_osi=Linux**
Disable the check of power state. Option two modifies the list of supported OS interface strings (changes the OS compatibility reported to the BIOS). Necessary on some broken BIOSes to make temperature/fan control work.

Full info found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions